# Safari float: left and hyphens: auto

Tags: html, css, safari

I have a some interesting bug in Safari (10, Mac) with element (display:inline-block and float: left) and hyphens: auto.
I can't float this icon to the text.
I use hyphens: auto, because there can be a long text link.

html:

```
<div class="main">
<a href="/">
<i class="fa fa-external-link" aria-hidden="true"></i> sometext_without_spacing_sometext_without_spacing_sometext_without_spacing_sometext_without_spacing_sometext_without_spacing_sometext_without_spacing_sometext_without_spacing_sometext_without_spacing_sometext_without_spacing_sometext_without_spacing_sometext_without_spacing</a>
</div>
```

css:

```
.main {
  width: 300px;
  word-break: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
}
.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

You can see this example on [codepen](http://codepen.io/llsandro/pen/LWMLWK):

and screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Thanks and have a nice day :)

Comment: I would expect safari's behaviour as there is a space between the icon and text that follows meaning because the next word is too long for the line, it would drop to the next line before word break is applied - firefox does the same as safari (although word break hasn't worked)

Comment: @Pete, I didn't check firefox. Thanks.

Comment: If you use overflow-wrap, then it looks like safari: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpqMPB

Comment: @Pete, unfortunately firefox doesn't work with this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpqMPB